# reconstructing drools StatefulKnowledgeSession after server restart

Tags: jboss, drools

Assume I created a StatefulKnowledgeSession from a given knowledgebase.
The JBPM process in this session can last for multiple days so we need to persist the session between invocations.

Now the knowledge resouces (JBPM Process definitions (BPMN files)) may change while a given process instance is running.

Upon server restart, I will need to reconstruct the correct knowledgebase in order to load the session.
But how do I know which resources to use to rebuild the knowledgebase?
Does a session keep track of the resources which were used to start it?
Do I need to build and manage knowledgebaseconfigurations?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Michiel

Answer (score 0):

Typically your application would recreate the kbase the same way it was created the first time.  So depending on how you create your kbase, this will involve simply loading the necessary processes again from classpath, from filesystem or from guvnor repository for example.

The session itself doesn't keep track of the kbase (so it can recreate it).

Kris

Comment: So I need to setup/maintain somekind of dictionary that contains the needed bpmn-files (specific version) in order to reconstruct the kbase, right?